# How to fix one div to the right side of another?

Tags: html, css

I have a vertical div with a thin white line on the left side. I would like the grey div to begin at the line.

**How could I make this the case?**

[image] Its a little hard to see but on the left side there is a thin white line.

Currently, I have in my css file:

```
.bottomPlayerDiv {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}



 .navDiv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(41, 41, 41, 1);
  width: 220px;

  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 220px;
}
```

HTML:

```
      <body>

    <div class="navDiv">

      <div class="logo">
        <img id="logoImage" src="images/logo.png">
      </div>

      <div class="navBarItems">
         <button class="profileItem">My Profile</button>
         <button class="exploreItem">Explore</button>
         <button class="uploadItem">Upload</button>
       </div>

  </div>

  <div class="bottomPlayerDiv">

    <div class="soundscapeImgDiv">
      <!-- <img id="soundscapeImg" src="images/testImg.png">
      <img id="pause/playIcon" src="images/pause.png"> -->
    </div>

  </div>
  ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following code snippet useful. You were adding `margin-right` which was appearing as a line.

```css
.bottomPlayerDiv { 
  background-color: grey; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 150px; 
  position: fixed; 
  bottom: 0px; 
  display: inline-block; 
  float: left; 
} 

.navDiv { 
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0px; 
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 220px; 
  display: inline-block; 
  float: left; 
} 
 
 .content { margin-left: 220px; }
```

```html
<div class="navDiv"></div>
<div class="bottomPlayerDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use case float property for each div and measure their width to be equal 100 combined!

Comment: Please add code sample to make this a usable answer